# Pass python variables into a command

Tags: python, shell, command

I'd like to pass variables 'first' and 'last' from my python snippet into a command.

Python code:

```
import csv
import dateutil.parser

with open('run.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   first = dateutil.parser.parse(reader.next()[3])
   for row in reader:
     pass
last = dateutil.parser.parse(row[3])
```

Command:

```
$ influx -execute="SELECT MEAN(value) FROM cpu_value WHERE time >= first and time <= last GROUP BY type,type_instance" -database=collectd  -format=csv -pretty=true
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to call `influx` from your Python script? Is it also written in Python?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, It need to call it inside python script. It's written in 'go'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preferably call influx from within python.
For this you can use python's `subprocess.check_call`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)

```
import csv
import dateutil.parser
import subprocess

with open('run.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   first = dateutil.parser.parse(reader.next()[3])
   for row in reader:
      pass
last = dateutil.parser.parse(row[3])

print (first,last)
command = "/opt/influxdb/influx -execute=\"SELECT MEAN(value) FROM cpu_value WHERE time >= {0} and time <= {1} GROUP BY type,type_instance\" -database=collectd  -format=csv -pretty=true".format(first, last)subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
```